# Select Data as per the given output

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Table 1:

| ID | CALLID | CALLSTATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | Generated |
| 2 | 321 | Not Generated |
| 3 | 343 | Generated |
| 4 | 567 | Not Generated |
| 5 | 789 | Generated |

Table 2:

| UID | ID | CALLID | GENERATEDATE | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | 123 | 2021/3/18 | 1 |
| 21 | 1 | 123 | 2021/4/20 | 1 |
| 31 | 1 | 123 | 2021/5/20 | 0 |
| 41 | 2 | 321 | NULL | NULL |
| 51 | 3 | 343 | 2021/4/21 | 1 |
| 61 | 4 | 567 | NULL | NULL |
| 71 | 5 | 789 | 2021/5/1 | 0 |

Output of Oracle should be like below table:

| ID | CALLID | GENERATEDATE | CALLSTATUS | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 2021/4/20 | Generated | 1 |
| 2 | 321 | NULL | Not Generated | NULL |
| 3 | 343 | 2021/4/21 | Generated | 1 |
| 4 | 567 | NULL | Not Generated | NULL |
| 5 | 789 | 2021/5/1 | Generated | 0 |

The output which I want should be like above table. For CALLID '123', as per table 2 last generated call is on '2021/5/20' but it's result is '0' which i don't want to select. It should select '2021/4/21' because it's result is '1'. But for CALLID '789', No RESULT is '1' so it should select Generated Date as '2021/5/1'.

Comment: This looks suspicously the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750009/select-id-whose-call-are-generated   Perkhaps you and Tia Mehara should be collaborating on your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation along with `NVL()` function depending on the values for the `result` column such as

```
SELECT t1.id, MAX(t1.callid) AS callid, 
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN result = 1 THEN t2.generatedate END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN NVL(result,0)!=1 THEN t2.generatedate END)) AS generateddate, 
       MAX(t1.callstatus) AS callstatus, MAX(result) AS result
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id         
   AND t2.callid = t1.callid       
 GROUP BY t1.id
 ORDER BY t1.id
```

| ID | CALLID | GENERATEDDATE | CALLSTATUS | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 20/04/2021 | Generated | 1 |
| 2 | 321 |  | Not Generated |  |
| 3 | 343 | 21/04/2021 | Generated | 1 |
| 4 | 567 |  | Not Generated |  |
| 5 | 789 | 01/05/2021 | Generated | 0 |

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d8297c75cd74a906004cad66813824ac)</kbd>

Comment: Hi @Barbaros , Could you please help me with this question - stackoverflow.com/q/67900122/16068042

Thank you..!!!

Comment: Hi @Barbaros , Please help me with this question - stackoverflow.com/q/67900122/16068042

Comment: Hi @Pikachu11 , excuse me, I'm busy now, perhaps I'll be able to check it out when I'm available and free :)